# Parsing column data using sed

Tags: bash, sed

My input file:

```
   SMOKE_TEST_FIMS,"['a', 'b', 'c']",2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000,100
   4.AIQM-B,,2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000,102
   000TEST2,['1.034820'],2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000,130
```

I want to parse the string in such a way that output file will look like below:

Expected output:

```
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS', 'a', '2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','b', '2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','c', '2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'4.AIQM-B','','2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000','102'
'000TEST2','1.034820','2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000','130'
```

I was able to parse the single column data ['a','b','c'] to

```
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
     sed -i "s/ *\"/'/g;s/ *[^0-9]*\('[^']*'\)\]*'*/\1/g;s/\(.\)''/\1'\n'/g;" updatebomStatement2.cql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything more interesting you should be using awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=",?\"?[][]\"?,?"; OFS="," }
{
    if (split($2,a,/\047/)) {
        for (j=2; j in a; j+=2) {
            $2 = a[j]
            prt()
        }
    }
    else {
        prt()
    }
}

function prt(   out) {
    out = "\047" $0 "\047"
    gsub(OFS,"\047,\047",out)
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','a','2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','b','2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','c','2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'4.AIQM-B','','2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000','102'
'000TEST2','1.034820','2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000','130'
```

or building on [@karakfa's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256169/1745001):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="([][ \"\047])*,([][ \"\047])*"; OFS="\047,\047" }
{
    for(i=2; i<=(NF-2); i++) {
        print "\047" $1, $i, $(NF-1), $NF "\047"
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','a','2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','b','2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','c','2015-08-01 14:00:00+0000','100'
'4.AIQM-B','','2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000','102'
'000TEST2','1.034820','2015-11-19 05:00:00+0000','130'
```

Comment: Sir above script works well. just have one doubt, can;t i write tst.awk inside of my .sh file?

Comment: Yes `awk 'script' file`. man awk. btw the English word is "question" not "doubt" - "doubt" implies you don't believe something.

Comment: yupp.. it should be a 'question'.. i apologize

Comment: No problem, I only mention it because it's such a common mistake by people who aren't native English speakers even when the rest of their English is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If you are are ok with an gnu awk solution here is such a script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { FPAT = "(\"[^\"]+\")|(\\[[^\\]]+\\])|([^,]*)" 
        OFS  = ","
      }

{ if ( $2~/\[[^\]]+/ ) {
    # sanitize input: strip ", [, ]:
    gsub(/[\[\]\"]/, "", $2)

    # split at "," into parts: and print them
    split($2, parts, ",")
    for( ind in parts ) {
        # further normalize input
        gsub(/^ ?'/, "", parts[ind])
        gsub(/'$/, "", parts[ind])
        tmp=sprintf("'%s','%s','%s','%s'", $1, parts[ind], $3, $4)
        print tmp
    }
  }
  else { 
      tmp=sprintf("'%s','%s','%s','%s'", $1, $2, $3, $4)
      print tmp
  }
}
```

Run it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`.

Imho gnu `awk` with its `FPAT` feature and its control statements is much better suited for your requirements than `sed`.

The first line with the `FPAT` describes what mades up a field in your input. It is either

- something inside double quotes `"`
- something inside brackets `[ ... ]`
- or something separated by comma

The if statement matches that bracket case which has to be split into several lines.

Answer (score 1):

alternative hacky `awk`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q="'" '{gsub(/[ "\]\[]/, ""); 
                              for(i=2;i <=NF-2; i++) 
                                 {$i=$i?$i:q q; 
                                  print q $1 q, $i, q $(NF-1) q,q $NF q}}' file

'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','a','2015-08-0114:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','b','2015-08-0114:00:00+0000','100'
'SMOKE_TEST_FIMS','c','2015-08-0114:00:00+0000','100'
'4.AIQM-B','','2015-04-1612:04:21+0000','102'
'000TEST2','1.034820','2015-11-1905:00:00+0000','130'
```

Comment: Not all awks will accept square brackets in a bracket expression by escaping them (may be gawk-only, idk) - portably you need to just put them at the front of the bracket expression, `[][ "]`. Also `$i=$i?$i:q q` might produce a syntax error on some awks due to the unparenthesized ternary expression and it'll fail for fields that evaluate numerically to zero, use `$i=($i==""?q q:"")` instead. Other than that, I like the idea but it can be simplified a bit if you include `\047` in the bracket expression since then EVERY field gets surrounding quotes added.

Comment: I edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37255830/1745001) to at the end show what I was getting at with my comment above about how it could be simplified. If you'd like to edit your answer to include that then Ill delete it from mine.

Comment: thanks for the comments, `\047` is a good idea to simplify quoting.

Comment: yeah, unlike `q="'"` you can use `\047` everywhere without complicating things, e.g.: to include `'` with other chars `a"c` in a test of a bracket expression is `/[a"c\047]/` vs `$0~"[a\"c"q"]"`.